# Unix awk command to return all matching lines

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have a file which looks like the below -

```
A
B
C
D
E

-----

A
B
C
D
C

---

X
Y
A
B
XEC

---
```

When the fifth row of each block is/contains E, I want the previous 4 lines to be returned. I wrote the below command but it is buggy

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0} $0~s {f=NR} END {print a[f-4]; print a[f-6]; print a[f-8];}' s="E" file.txt
```

But it is returning only the last match. I want all the matched lines to be returned.

For the above entries, the output needs to be

```
A
B
C
D
---

X
Y
A
B
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you really have **`---`** lines in file, as shown in question?

Comment: Yes, I do have those lines :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gawk` : multi-character RS is only supported in gnu-awk

```
awk -v RS='\n\n[-]+\n\n*' -v FS="\n" '$5 ~ /E/{printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n---\n",$1,$2,$3,$4}' inputfile
A
B
C
D
---
X
Y
A
B
---
```

Comment: ++ but do mention multi-character `RS` is only supported in gnu-awk

Answer (score 3):

Not sure really how you want, you really need `---` and then newline char ???

Using `tac` and `awk` you can try below one

- Print the N records after some regexp:

  `awk -v n=4 'c&&c--;/regexp/{c=n}' <input_file>`
- Print the N records before some regexp:

  `tac <input_file> | awk -v n=4 'c&&c--;/regexp/{c=n}' | tac`

  ```
   ^                       ^              ^              ^
   |                       |              |              |
  reverse file  no of lines to print  when regexp found  again reverse
  ```

**Input**

```
$ cat infile
A
B
C
D
E

-----

A
B
C
D
C

---

X
Y
A
B
XEC

---
```

When `n=4`

```
$ tac infile | awk -v n=4 'c&&c--;/E/{c=n}' | tac
A
B
C
D
X
Y
A
B
```

When `n=2`

```
$ tac infile | awk -v n=2 'c&&c--;/E/{c=n}' | tac
C
D
A
B
```

Comment: I would need some separator between the entries for further processing the file. Thanks for your command, I will give it a try.

Comment: @maddie try `tac infile | awk -v n=4 'c==n{print "---"}c&&c--;/E/{c=n}' | tac`